# Is it possible to write plain java/c++ programs in android studio

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio, intellij-idea

Is it possible to write plain java and c++ programs in android studio(not ndk development), want to avoid installing separate IDEs for java/c++ programs.

Comment: You might be able to open an existing Java project (have not tried this).  But the Android development team have remove (from the wizard) the ability to create a standard (standalone) Java project.  You could download  Jet brains - IntelliJ IDEA for your standalone projects to have a similar IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to write c++ in android studio. Android studio is based on Jet brains - IntelliJ IDEA which allows you to create android projects so that would cover all your Java projects.

Jet brains have a tool called resharper for .net / c++ projects. https://www.jetbrains.com/dotnet/

Comment: JetBrains also have CLion which is a new and exciting C++ IDE offering :D